# For a matrix $W$, does $WW^*+W^*W=I$ imply anything particularly nice about $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Specifically $W$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix whose diagonal entries are $0$. I know this is an open ended question. I'm conjugating a matrix $R$ by $W$ and trying to do anything entry wise hasn't been fruitful, so I'm hoping the fact $W$ looks like it is almost unitary, but not quite, could lead to something. I'm just wondering if this is a kind of matrix people study.

Comment: is $W^*$ the conjugate matrix or the conjugate transposed?

Comment: Conjugate transpose

Answer (score 1):

Let $W=\pmatrix{0&a\\ b&0}$. The given condition implies that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned where $W$ came from. It is exactly a matrix whose off diagonal entries are the coordinates of a point on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^2$.